# How to dynamically assign properties and values to an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to assign properties and values to an object initialized as empty.
However, it keeps on prompting the Error: Cannot assign properties of undefined (setting '0' ).
Note "duplicate" is a copy of the text gotten using the map method in some code lines above.

I am using a for loop for this assignment.
The code snippet is shown below.

```
 //Initialise an object to hold array data
    const dataStore = {};
 //Note: text is an array of string

    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        let dataStoreKeyCounter = 0;
        if ((Object.hasOwn(dataStore, text[i])) !== true)
        {
            for (let j = 0; j < duplicate.length; j++)
            {
                if (text[i] == duplicate[j])
                {
                    dataStoreKeyCounter++;
                }
            }
            //Set the text as the a property and the counter as its value.
            dataStore.text[i] = dataStoreKeyCounter;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps `dataStore.text[i]` supposed to be `dataStore[text[i]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you put `dataStore.text[i]`. You have not declared `dataStore.text`. After declaring your object, do `dataStore.text = {}`

Also, make sure your duplicate is created by

```
let duplicate = {...dataStore}
```

This way, an edit to the original or the duplicate will not affect the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the following line:

`dataStore.text[i] = dataStoreKeyCounter;`

To this:

`dataStore[text[i]] = dataStoreKeyCounter;`

This will first evaluate the value of `text[i]` and then pass it into `dataStore` as the key giving you the "dynamic" nature you are looking for.

The difference here is that when you access like this `dataStore[key]`, if the key is not present in the Object, it is created.

Whereas, if you access `dataStore.key`, if key is not present, it will return `undefined`